# Pandas Split column into multiple columns by multiple string delimiters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
id    info
1     Name: John Age: 12 Sex: Male
2     Name: Sara Age: 22 Sex: Female
3     Name: Mac Donald Age: 32 Sex: Male
```

I'm looking to split the info column into 3 columns such that i get the final output as:

```
id  Name      Age   Sex
1   John      12   Male
2   Sara      22   Female
3 Mac Donald  32   Male
```

I tried using pandas split function.

```
df[['Name','Age','Sex']] = df.info.split(['Name'])
```

I might have to do this multiple times to get desired output.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

PS: The info column also contains `NaN` values

Answer (score 6):

Using Regex with named groups.

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col": ['Name: John Age: 12 Sex: Male', 'Name: Sara Age: 22 Sex: Female', 'Name: Mac Donald Age: 32 Sex: Male']})
df = df['Col'].str.extract(r"Name:\s*(?P<Name>[A-Za-z\s]+)\s*Age:\s*(?P<Age>\d+)\s*Sex:\s*(?P<Sex>Male|Female)") # Or if spacing is standard use df['Col'].str.extract(r"Name: (?P<Name>[A-Za-z\s]+) Age: (?P<Age>\d+) Sex: (?P<Sex>Male|Female)")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
          Name Age     Sex
0        John   12    Male
1        Sara   22  Female
2  Mac Donald   32    Male
```

Comment: This solution creates whitespace. If you do `df['Name'].to_list()`, you will return: `['John ', 'Sara ', 'Mac Donald ']` A simple `str.strip()` could fix this as the regex would get more intense.

Answer (score 2):

The regex is pretty tough to write / read, so you could replace with `,` for where you want separate into new columns and use `str.split()` and pass `expand=True`. You will need to set the result back to three new columns that you create with `df[['Name', 'Age', 'Sex']]`:

```
df[['Name', 'Age', 'Sex']] = (df['info'].replace(['Name: ', ' Age: ', ' Sex: '], ['',',',','], regex=True)
                              .str.split(',', expand=True))
df

Out[1]: 
   id                                info        Name Age     Sex
0   1        Name: John Age: 12 Sex: Male        John  12    Male
1   2      Name: Sara Age: 22 Sex: Female        Sara  22  Female
2   3  Name: Mac Donald Age: 32 Sex: Male  Mac Donald  32    Male
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick oneliner can be

```
df[['Name', 'Age', 'Sex']] = df['info'].str.split('\s?\w+:\s?', expand=True).iloc[:, 1:]
```

Split using `someword:` and then add new columns.

Comment: Aaah, I forgot about `\w+`. Nice! However, this creates whitespace, so you either need to do `str.strip()` or improve the regex. For starters, you can do `\w+: ` instead of  `\w+:`, but that only gets rid of the last space.

Comment: Strip won't help and this doesn't create whitespace. The extra column is due to the fact that the string starts with the split string. @DavidErickson

Comment: If you do `df['Name'].to_list()` or `df['Age'].to_list()`, you will see that there is a `' '` before and after each string

Comment: Oh! You mean after I get the result. Yeah, strip should take care of that.

Comment: Yes, for example `df['Age'].to_list()` returns: `[' 12 ', ' 22 ', ' 32 ']` There is a similar issue in Rakesh's answer, bit only for the `Name` column.

Comment: is there a way to automatically assign column names? because I had similar problem where in the `info` column is really huge and I would like to put them in multiple columns. For eg a record might look like `a:1 b:2 c:3 d:4 ........... pop:500` and I would like to have column names created automatically.

Comment: @Regressor Do a split and assign to new variable `x = df.info.str.split('regex', expand=True)` and then assign columns if you need custom column names `x.columns = ['a', 'b', ......]`.

Comment: thanks. Though I want the column names automatically generated from the `info` column in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def process_row(row):
        items = row.info.split(' ')
        row['Name']=str(items[1]).strip()
        row['Age']=str(items[3]).strip()
        row['Sex']=str(items[5]).strip()
        return row

  df=pd.DataFrame({"info": ['Name: John Age: 12 Sex: Male', 'Name: Sara Age: 22 Sex: 
     Female', 'Name: Mac Donald Age: 32 Sex: Male']})
  df['Name']=pd.NA #empty cell
  df['Age']=pd.NA #empty cell
  df['Sex']=pd.NA #empty cell

  df[['info','Name','Age','Sex']]=df.apply(process_row, axis=1, result_type="expand")
```