# Python Split Object into multiple String using delimiters

Tags: python, pandas

I have try many way, but there are error or N/A for those solution, can any people help me split the data? (Error: ValueError: Columns must be same length as key). The Data Type Is object

|  | prices |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [Apr 26 2013 01: +0, 13.326, 22] |
| 2 | [Apr 27 2013 01: +0, 14.301, 49] |

INTO Something like this

|  | date | price | volumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 26/04/2013 | 13.326 | 22 |
| 2 | 27/04/2013 | 14.301 | 49 |

Comment: Is your Prices column a string or a list of strings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Split column into multiple columns by multiple string delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63879459/pandas-split-column-into-multiple-columns-by-multiple-string-delimiters)

Comment: It data type is object

Comment: there is a ValueError: Columns must be same length as key error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have data in `['date','price','volume']` format, you can extract columns as follows.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'date_price_volume' : [['Apr 26 2013 01: +0', 13.326, 22],['Apr 27 2013 01: +0', 14.301, 49]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(df['date_price_volume'].to_list(), columns=['date','price','volume'])
df
```